# sshfs and Emacs: file changed on the disk

Tags: ssh, mount, osx, emacs, sshfs

I am using

Mac 10.6.8
SSHFS version 2.4
fuse4x library version: FUSE 2.8.7 / fuse4x 0.9.2

I connect via sshfs to a remote cluster (via a bridge). I modify the remote files with emacs. The problem is that emacs very often tells me that a file that I modifying has changed on the disk. I have used sshfs successfully and without error on other client, but with the same cluster. I can't understand the origin of this behavior, could it be that the internet connection is not very stable?

This problem is very serious because I have experienced data loss in more of one occasion. Is there something I can do, maybe changing come option of ssh? currently I have the following configuration:

```
Host            remote
HostName        localhost
Port            2222
HostKeyAlias    remote.address
User            username


Host            bridge
HostName        bridge.address
HostKeyAlias    bridge
User            username
TCPKeepAlive    no
LocalForward    localhost:2222 remote:22
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I suggest you use Emacs's TRAMP mode instead of sshfs. It's more flexible, and is likely to be faster after setting up the initial connection.

Comment: I am using Emacs's TRAMP mode and it works very fine, much better then sshfs.